# react redux update state from loop in nested array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a state like :

```
data: Object
  value: []
```

and I have some return value like:

```
{'name': 'myname'}
{'gender': 'male'}
```

Here I want to update each value simoltaneously calling dispatch:

When I call `dispatch({data}, type: ADD_DATA})` where data are each values in loop. I want the result like:

```
data: Object
    value: [{
         'type': 'personal',
        'info':[
          {'name': 'myname'},
          {'gender': 'male'}
        ]
    }]
```

I am stuck at here :

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {data: Object.assign({}, state.data, {value: null})})
```

Can I get some help ?

Comment: Can you be more precise on your exact problem, please. Given only your input it is very hard to create your wanted output, as it is not clear, where to put it into that nested result?

Answer (score 0):

```
var person = {
  type: 'personal',
  info: yourDataHere
};
return Object.assign({}, state, {data: Object.assign({}, data, {
  value: state.data.value.concat(person)
})});
```

I'm assuming that `yourDataHere` is

```
[
  {'name': 'myname'},
  {'gender': 'male'}
]
```

Comment: Note that we recommend using reducer composition instead of long chains of `Object.assign()` calls. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667775/state-in-redux-react-app-has-a-property-with-the-name-of-the-reducer/35674297#35674297 for an example of reducer composition.