# State in redux/react app has a property with the name of the reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, redux

I am creating an app using Redux and React. I run into a problem where I cannot map state to component properties since the state has a property that matches the name of the reducer I used.

The root reducer is created with `combineReducers` method

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  appReducer
});
```

The initial state is

```
const initialState = {
  sources: [], 
  left: {}, 
  right: {},
  diff: {} 
}
```

However in the component function `mapStateToProps`:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    sources: state.sources
  }
}
```

The `state.sources` is `undefined` because the value of `state` parameter is

```
{
  appReducer: {
    sources: [], 
    left: {}, 
    right: {}, 
    diff: {}
  }
}
```

Is this a feature of redux? So when I use more reducers, all of them will add new property to `state` variable? Or is there something wrong on my side (I never noticed this behavior in redux tutorials).

Thanks

Comment: your code is correct `state.appReducer. sources` you need the reducer name

Comment: Imagine you have 2,3 reducers every reducer has `sources` property

Comment: you can get specific `sources` by  `state.appReducer. sources` and ` state.appReducer.2 sources`

Comment: What you're describing is part of what `combineReducers` does.

Comment: I'll read the documentation next time :( Thanks for help.

Comment: you need to set "state = initialState.sources" in a appReducer to update/access specific state

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you only have a single reducer, you don’t need `combineReducers()`. Just use it directly:

```
const initialState = {
  sources: [],
  left: {},
  right: {}
}
function app(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'ADD_SOURCE':
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      sources: [...state.sources, action.newSource]
    })
  case 'ADD_SOURCE_TO_LEFT':
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      left: Object.assign({}, state.left, {
        [action.sourceId]: true
      })
    })
  case 'ADD_SOURCE_TO_RIGHT':
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      right: Object.assign({}, state.right, {
        [action.sourceId]: true
      })
    })
  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

Now you can create a store with that reducer:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
const store = createStore(app)
```

And connect a component to it:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  sources: state.sources
})
```

However your reducer is hard to read because it update many different things at once. Now, **this** is the moment you want to split it into several independent reducers:

```
function sources(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'ADD_SOURCE':
    return [...state.sources, action.newSource]
  default:
    return state
  }
}

function left(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'ADD_SOURCE_TO_LEFT':
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      [action.sourceId]: true
    })
  default:
    return state
  }    
}

function right(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'ADD_SOURCE_TO_RIGHT':
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      [action.sourceId]: true
    })
  default:
    return state
  }    
}

function app(state = {}, action) {
  return {
    sources: sources(state.sources, action),
    left: left(state.left, action),
    right: right(state.right, action),
  }
}
```

This is easier to maintain and understand, and it also makes it easier to change and test reducers independently.

Finally, as the last step, we can use `combineReducers()` to generate the root `app` reducer instead of writing it by hand:

```
// function app(state = {}, action) {
//   return {
//     sources: sources(state.sources, action),
//     left: left(state.left, action),
//     right: right(state.right, action),
//   }
// }

import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
const app = combineReducers({
  sources,
  left,
  right
})
```

There is no large benefit to using `combineReducers()` instead of writing the root reducer by hand except that it’s slightly more efficient and will likely save you a few typos. Also, you can apply this pattern more than once in your app: it’s fine to combine unrelated reducers into a single reducer several times in a nested way.

All this refactoring would have no effect on the components.

I would suggest you to watch my [free Egghead course on Redux](https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux) which covers this pattern of **reducer composition** and shows how `combineReducers()` is implemented.

Comment: Thanks Dan for explanation and the link to those videos.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, I believe your initial state would be:

```
{
  appReducer: {
    sources: [],
    left: {},
    right: {},
    diff: {}
  }
}
```

This is because `combineReducers` works by taking the name of the reducer, and mapping its contents to that name.

Also, just a note, but if you're going to use more than 1 reducer, the names of your reducers should be more specific than `appReducer`, and (just my personal opinion) they don't need the word `reducer`. A typical app might look like this:

```
combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  messages: messagesReducer,
  notifications: notificationsReducer
});
```

Then, your state could be accessed like:

```
state.user.email
state.messages[0]
```

Comment: You're right. Should I then change the `initialState` object accordingly?

Comment: The idea is each branch of the reducer is responsible for its own `initialState`. Your root reducer should have no initialState, and each reducer should only include its stuff. So your `appReducer` would be an object with keys for sources, left, right, etc.